# to let something into the hand of chance

Tags: expressions

Imagine for instance that you let the learning of a particular skill to "the hand of chance". Nothing is planned, nor organised to learn this skill, you might just learned it by chance, if you do, but... there is good chance you won't.

What about this one:

> "you let your education into the hand of chance"

I want to keep the idea of hazardous and high risk of failure.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: We would say "**put** X into the hand of chance" or, more likely, just "leave X to chance". An even more fatalistic expression would be "Leave X to the gods".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common idiom with this intent is to **[leave to chance](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+to+chance)**. For your example sentence, this would be worded:

> You left your education to chance.

Alternatively, you can use **fate**.

> You left your education to fate.

This adds a sense of one's education being completely out of one's control. Whereas, with chance, there's a possibility that one could *accidentally* or *unintentionally* influence the outcome.

---

Your current wording is a bit clunky and almost sounds biblical. However, one might more naturally say

> You let your education *fall* into the hand of chance.

Comment: Pluralizing hands helps. "hands of fate" is the appropriate idiom.

Comment: Alternatively, ["Manos: The Hands of Fate"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060666/)

Comment: @LukeWillis thanks! "a bit clunky and almost sounds biblical", thanks for those expressions, I love them!